# Get query params/string from ColdFusion request

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, taffy

I can't get query params inside ColdFusion component.

I tried to use:

- `<cfparam name="url.q2" default="">`
- `cgi.QUERY_STRING`
- `arguments`

All empty

I have a component:

```
<cfcomponent extends="taffy.core.resource" taffy:uri="/public/test" hint="some hint about this resource">
    <cffunction name="get" access="public" output="false">
        <cfparam name="url.query_p1" default="">
        <cfparam name="url.p2" default="">

        <cfset result = structNew() />

        <cfset result['arguments'] = arguments />
        <cfset result['cgi'] = cgi />
        <cfset result['QUERY_STRING'] = cgi.QUERY_STRING />
        <cfset result['url'] = url />

        <cfreturn representationOf(result).withStatus(200) />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And use this url for test: `http://localhost/public/test?query_p=1&p2=test`

As response I got:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "arguments": {
        "endpoint": "/public/test/",
        "type": "candidate"
    },
    "QUERY_STRING": "endpoint=/public/test/",
    "url": {
        "endpoint": "/public/test/",
        "query_p1": "",
        "p2": ""
    },
    "cgi": {
        "query_string": "endpoint=/public/test/",
        "request_url": "http://localhost/index.cfm?endpoint=/public/test/",

    }
}
```

How can I get something like? :

```
query_p=1
p2=test
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
<cfcomponent extends="taffy.core.resource" taffy:uri="/public/test" hint="some hint about this resource">
<cffunction name="get" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="query_p1" default="">
    <cfargument name="p2" default="">


    <cfreturn rep(arguments)>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

You can see additional Taffy Examples at

https://github.com/jmohler1970/Taffy_Verbs_withCache/blob/master/resources/users/users_id.cfc

Disclaimer: This is my sample code

Comment: not working.
I tried as approach and example code...
I got empty response

Comment: What do you get when you hit: `http://localhost/index.cfm?endpoint=public/test&query_p=1&p2=test`

Comment: `404 Not Found` . If I comment part with `<cfargument` it will return status 200

Comment: I should have had cfargument. I have now corrected the code.

Comment: As for the not found, you need to make sure you are running ColdFusion on the appropriate port.